# RecyclerView with items of different height: Scrollbar

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, scrollbar

I have a `RecyclerView` with items of varying heights with a scrollbar. 
Because of the different heights of the items, the scrollbar changes it's vertical size, dependent on which items are currently displayed (see screenshots). 
I have created an example project that displays the problem [here](https://github.com/fweigl/ScrollbarExample).

1. Has anyone had the same problem and fixed it?
2. How can I override the calculation of the scrollbar height and position to come up with an own implementation?

**EDIT:** The scrollbar's position and height can be controlled by overriding `RecyclerViews` `computeVerticalScrollOffset`, `computeVerticalScrollRange` and `computeVerticalScrollExtent`.
I have no idea though on how to implement these to make the scrollbar work properly with dynamic item heights.

The problem, I reckon, is that `RecyclerView` estimates the total height of all items based on the items currently visible and sets position and height of the scrollbar accordingly. One way to solve this might be to give a better estimation of the total height of all items.

[image: large scrollbar]
[image: small scrollbar]

Comment: It seems to me the problem is that you have a scroll view inside your recycler view, do you?

Comment: @azizbekian No that's not the case.

Comment: Have you a constant number of rows ? I don't think you can manage this if it is variable. Given the nature of RV, you have the height just when are fetched

Comment: What is the problem to be exact?I dint get

Comment: I have answered to your problems in this SO post https://stackoverflow.com/a/49233865/8007959

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The best way to handle this situation may be to somehow calculate the scroll bar range based on the size of each item. That may not be practical or desirable. In lieu of that, here is a simple implementation of a custom RecyclerView that you can play with to try to get what you want. It will show you how you can use the various scroll methods to control the scroll bar. It will stick the size of the thumb to an initial size based upon the number of items displayed. The key thing to remember is that the scroll range is arbitrary but all other measurements (extent, offset) must use the same units.

See the documentation for [`computeVerticalScrollRange()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#computeVerticalScrollRange()).

Here is a video of the result.

[image]

**Update:** The code has been updated to correct a few issues: The movement of the thumb is less jerky and the thumb will now come to rest at the bottom as the `RecyclerView` scrolls to the bottom. There are also a few caveats that are given after the code.

**MyRecyclerView.java (updated)**

```
public class MyRecyclerView extends RecyclerView {
    // The size of the scroll bar thumb in our units.
    private int mThumbHeight = UNDEFINED;

    // Where the RecyclerView cuts off the views when the RecyclerView is scrolled to top.
    // For example, if 1/4 of the view at position 9 is displayed at the bottom of the RecyclerView,
    // mTopCutOff will equal 9.25. This value is used to compute the scroll offset.
    private float mTopCutoff = UNDEFINED;

    public MyRecyclerView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyRecyclerView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MyRecyclerView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves the size of the scroll bar thumb in our arbitrary units.
     *
     * @return Scroll bar thumb height
     */
    @Override
    public int computeVerticalScrollExtent() {
        return (mThumbHeight == UNDEFINED) ? 0 : mThumbHeight;
    }

    /**
     * Compute the offset of the scroll bar thumb in our scroll bar range.
     *
     * @return Offset in scroll bar range.
     */
    @Override
    public int computeVerticalScrollOffset() {
        return (mTopCutoff == UNDEFINED) ? 0 : (int) ((getCutoff() - mTopCutoff) * ITEM_HEIGHT);
    }

    /**
     * Computes the scroll bar range. It will simply be the number of items in the adapter
     * multiplied by the given item height. The scroll extent size is also computed since it
     * will not vary. Note: The RecyclerView must be positioned at the top or this method
     * will throw an IllegalStateException.
     *
     * @return The scroll bar range
     */
    @Override
    public int computeVerticalScrollRange() {
        if (mThumbHeight == UNDEFINED) {
            LinearLayoutManager lm = (LinearLayoutManager) getLayoutManager();
            int firstCompletePositionw = lm.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();

            if (firstCompletePositionw != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                if (firstCompletePositionw != 0) {
                    throw (new IllegalStateException(ERROR_NOT_AT_TOP_OF_RANGE));
                } else {
                    mTopCutoff = getCutoff();
                    mThumbHeight = (int) (mTopCutoff * ITEM_HEIGHT);
                }
            }
        }
        return getAdapter().getItemCount() * ITEM_HEIGHT;
    }

    /**
     * Determine where the RecyclerVIew display cuts off the list of views. The range is
     * zero through (getAdapter().getItemCount() - 1) inclusive.
     *
     * @return The position in the RecyclerView where the displayed views are cut off. If the
     * bottom view is partially displayed, this will be a fractional number.
     */
    private float getCutoff() {
        LinearLayoutManager lm = (LinearLayoutManager) getLayoutManager();
        int lastVisibleItemPosition = lm.findLastVisibleItemPosition();

        if (lastVisibleItemPosition == RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
            return 0f;
        }

        View view = lm.findViewByPosition(lastVisibleItemPosition);
        float fractionOfView;

        if (view.getBottom() < getHeight()) { // last visible position is fully visible
            fractionOfView = 0f;
        } else { // last view is cut off and partially displayed
            fractionOfView = (float) (getHeight() - view.getTop()) / (float) view.getHeight();
        }
        return lastVisibleItemPosition + fractionOfView;
    }

    private static final int ITEM_HEIGHT = 1000; // Arbitrary, make largish for smoother scrolling
    private static final int UNDEFINED = -1;
    private static final String ERROR_NOT_AT_TOP_OF_RANGE
            = "RecyclerView must be positioned at the top of its range.";
}
```

**Caveats**
The following issues may need to be addressed depending on the implementation.

The sample code works only for vertical scrolling. The sample code also assumes that the contents of the `RecyclerView` are static. Any updates to the data backing the `RecyclerView` may cause scrolling issues. If any changes are made that effect the height of any view displayed on the first full screen of the `RecyclerView`, the scrolling will be off. Changes below that will probably work OK. This is due to how the code calculates the scrolling offset.

To determine the base value for the scrolling offset, (variable `mTopCutOff`), the RecyclerView must be scrolled to the top the first time `computeVerticalScrollRange()` is invoked so views can be measured; otherwise, the code will stop with an "IllegalStateException". This is especially troublesome on an orientation change if the `RecyclerView` is scrolled at all. A simple way around this would be to inhibit restoration of the scrolling position so it defaults to the top on an orientation change.

*(The following is probably not the best solution...)*

```
var lm: LinearLayoutManager = object : LinearLayoutManager(this) {
    override fun onRestoreInstanceState(state: Parcelable?) {
        // Don't restore
    }
}
```

I hope this helps. (btw, your MCVE made this a lot easier.)

Comment: Works quite well, thanks alot! Also: "The key thing to remember is that the scroll range is arbitrary", great find, I tried calculating sizes in pixels.

Comment: @Ascorbin Thanks for the bounty. I was a little dissatisfied with the way my example was working - the thumb did not land at the right time and a few other things that irked me. I have an update and will post an edit to my answer if you are interested. I don't usually like to go back to update accepted answers, but what I would post is not significantly different and may be helpful.

Comment: Cool, looking forward.

Comment: @Ascorbin Updates made.

Comment: I've implemented a slightly modified version of your solution already and have not seen any problems yet, but I'll test the edge cases you mentioned and will adapt your improvements.
 Thank you very much for your efford.

Comment: @Cheticamp how about rotation screen in the middle height of the list? Is there any way to calculate missing part?

Comment: @deadfish I have implemented an alternative solution below based on Cheticamp's which doesn't have those limitations, meaning it also works consistently even after orientation changes!

Answer (score 1):

Use item positions as metric of scroll progress. This will cause your scroll indicator to become a bit jumpy, but at least it will remain fixed-sized.

There are multiple implementations of custom scroll indicators for RecyclerView. Most double as fast scrollers.

Here is [my own implementation](https://github.com/chdir/fdutil/blob/master/app/src/main/java/net/sf/fakenames/fddemo/view/DirFastScroller.java), based on [RecyclerViewFastScroller library](https://github.com/danoz73/RecyclerViewFastScroller). Basically, one have to create a custom View subclass, that will be animated, similarly to ScrollView and DrawerLayout:

- Store current offset
- During animation offset position of thumb View via `View#offset*` calls
- During layout set position based on current offset.

You probably don't want to start learning all that magic now, just use some existing fast scrolling library (RecyclerViewFastScroller or one of it's clones).

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by [Cheticamp's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46164933/2343010) I managed to spin my own extension of RecyclerView which doesn't have the `computeVerticalScrollRange` limitations.
In fact, this alternative solution doesn't require extending `computeVerticalScrollRange` at all.

By reasoning with things in terms of spans I managed to think of a solution that doesn't depend on calculating the height of any items in the RecyclerView.

Each item in the list has a span of 1, and I am *fixing* the scrollbar thumb size to a certain number of spans (meaning the scrollbar doesn't change its height as the user scrolls).

Now consider the following things:

- `rangeSpanCount` to be the number of spans a.k.a the number of items in the adapter
- `firstSpan` to be the position of the first visible span (first completely visible if any, otherwise the first partially visible)
- `lastSpan` to be the position of the last visible span (last completely visible if any, otherwise the last partially visible)
- `visibleSpanCount`, equal to `lastSpan - firstSpan`, to be the number of spans currently visible in the screen
- `remainingSpanCount`, equal to `rangeSpanCount - 1 - visibleSpanCount`, to be the number of spans remaining in the RecyclerView

Then for the sake of the explanation assume we have a list of 9 spans, and only 3 of them can be visible at any given time (although the logic holds even if the number of visible spans at a given moment is dynamic):

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

0 1 2{------------}
                |    the size of this range is:
{--}2 3 4       |===========>  rangeSpanCount - 1 - visibleSpanCount

{-----}3 4 5

{-------}4 5 6

{-----------}6 7 8

{-------------}7 8 9
       |   you can see that this range is simply computed as:
       |===========> firstSpan - 0
```

Then notice how we can use the range that grows as the scrolling from top to bottom happens *and* the range of spans that is left out of sight at any given moment to calculate the progress of the scrolling throughout the RecyclerView.

First we figure out how much has the growing range grown:

```
partialProgress = (firstSpan - 0) / remainingSpanCount
```

(From 0% all the way to 100% when `firstSpan == remainingSpanCount`)

Then we calculate which span among the visible ones better represent the progress of the scrolling throughout the RecyclerView. Basically, we want to make sure the first span (of position `0`) is chosen when RecyclerView is at the very top and the last span (of position `rangeSpanCount - 1`) to be chosen when we reach the very bottom. This is important otherwise your scrolling will be off when reaching these edges.

```
progressSpan = firstSpan + (visibleSpanCount * partialProgress)
```

And finally, you can use the position of this chosen span and the total number of spans to figure out the actual progress percentage across the RecyclerView, and use the real computed scroll range to determine the best offset for the scrollbar:

```
scrollProgress = progressSpan / rangeSpanCount

scrollOffset = scrollProgress * super.computeVerticalScrollRange()
```

And that's it! This solution can be adapted to support the horizontal axis, so it carries none of the caveats from Cheticamp's alternative.

*It has one caveat, though*: the movement of the scrollbar thumb is discrete, not continuous along the axis, meaning the jumping from one position to the next is noticeable. It is consistent, though, never "shaking" itself / going back and forth while the user performs a scroll to any direction.

This caveat can probably be solved by working with a much higher number of spans in respect to the number of items in the adapter (e.g. having multiple spans per item) but I didn't give it too much thought right now.

I hope my explanation is reasonably clear... and I thank you all for helping me with your answers, it really helped point me to the right direction!

Below you can check out the complete solution and source code:

```
package cz.nn.calllog.view.utils.recyclerview

import android.content.Context
import android.util.AttributeSet
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView


class SmartScrollbarRecyclerView(
    context: Context,
    attributeSet: AttributeSet?,
    defaultStyleAttribute: Int
) : RecyclerView(context, attributeSet, defaultStyleAttribute) {

    constructor(
        context: Context,
        attributeSet: AttributeSet
    ) : this(context, attributeSet, 0)

    constructor(
        context: Context
    ) : this(context, null, 0)

    override fun computeVerticalScrollExtent(): Int {
        return checkCalculationPrerequisites(
            onFailure = {
                super.computeVerticalScrollExtent()
            },
            onSuccess = { _, rangeSpan, scrollRange ->

                val extentSpanCount = 1.5F
                val scrollExtent = (extentSpanCount / rangeSpan)

                (scrollExtent * scrollRange).toInt()
            }
        )
    }

    override fun computeVerticalScrollOffset(): Int {
        return checkCalculationPrerequisites(
            onFailure = {
                super.computeVerticalScrollOffset()
            },
            onSuccess = { layoutManager, rangeSpanCount, scrollRange ->

                val firstSpanPosition = calculateFirstVisibleItemPosition(layoutManager)
                val lastSpanPosition = calculateLastVisibleItemPosition(layoutManager)
                val visibleSpanCount = lastSpanPosition - firstSpanPosition

                val remainingSpanCount = rangeSpanCount - 1 - visibleSpanCount

                val partialProgress = (firstSpanPosition / remainingSpanCount)
                val progressSpanPosition = firstSpanPosition + (visibleSpanCount * partialProgress)
                val scrollProgress = progressSpanPosition / rangeSpanCount

                (scrollProgress * scrollRange).toInt()
            }
        )
    }

    private fun calculateFirstVisibleItemPosition(layoutManager: LinearLayoutManager): Int {
        val firstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition = layoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()
        return if (firstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition == -1) {
            layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition()
        } else {
            firstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition
        }
    }

    private fun calculateLastVisibleItemPosition(layoutManager: LinearLayoutManager): Int {
        val lastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition = layoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()
        return if (lastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition == -1) {
            layoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition()
        } else {
            lastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition
        }
    }

    private fun checkCalculationPrerequisites(
        onFailure: () -> Int,
        onSuccess: (LinearLayoutManager, Float, Int) -> Int
    ): Int {

        val layoutManager = layoutManager

        if (layoutManager !is LinearLayoutManager) {
            return onFailure.invoke()
        }

        val scrollRange = computeVerticalScrollRange()
        if (scrollRange < height) {
            return 0
        }

        val rangeSpanCount = calculateRangeSpanCount()
        if (rangeSpanCount == 0F) {
            return 0
        }

        return onSuccess.invoke(layoutManager, rangeSpanCount, scrollRange)
    }

    private fun calculateRangeSpanCount(): Float {
        val recyclerAdapter = adapter ?: return 0F
        return recyclerAdapter.itemCount.toFloat()
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If I'm not mistaken the attribute `android:scollBarSize="Xdp"` should work for you. Add it to your `RecyclerView` xml.

That way you decide the size, and it will remain fixed.

Comment: Nice idea, unfortunately scrollBarSize defines the horizontal size / width of the scrollbar, not it's height.