# RecyclerView fast scroll thumb height too small for large data set

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am using the default `RecyclerView` fast scroll and I followed [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46026362/6181476) to support it.

Now, the problem is that the thumb resizes its height as per the size of the data set. For large items like 100 and above, the thumb becomes very small and almost becomes difficult to respond to dragging.

Please is there any way I can set minimum height for the fast scroll thumb.

Comment: Same problem in my App. Can we define a fix thumb, which is not getting small depending on the list size?

Comment: Same problem in my App

Comment: The above answer is very limited. Here's an [example](https://bitbucket.org/StylingAndroid/scrollingrecyclerview/src/2fc7d871b911144b492744bb3a5097bb01869ac1?at=Part1) of what you want to do.

Comment: @BurakCakir, what do you mean by saying *"the above answer"*?

Comment: @azizbekian the SO answer when you click [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45370246/how-to-use-fastscrollenabled-in-recyclerview/46026362#46026362).

Comment: Same problem in my app. is fix your the problem?

Comment: @BurakCakir this is not the answer people looking for here. Anybody found solutions to this yet?

Comment: I made a library that fixes it, here: https://github.com/AndroidDeveloperLB/FastScrollerAndRecyclerViewFixes . Explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65858514/878126

Answer (score 6):

This is only a partial answer; I'm missing (at least) one piece of the puzzle, but hopefully someone else can figure it out.

Once you've added the necessary attributes to your `<RecyclerView>` tag (as mentioned in the answer linked in OP's question), the sizing/positioning of the scrollbar thumb is controlled by three methods inside `LinearLayoutManager`:

- `int computeVerticalScrollRange()`: The size of the scrollbar's track.
- `int computeVerticalScrollExtent()`: The size of the scrollbar's thumb.
- `int computeVerticalScrollOffset()`: The distance between the top of the scrollbar's track and the top of the scrollbar's thumb.

The units for these methods is arbitrary; you can use anything you'd like as long as all three methods share the same units. By default, `LinearLayoutManager` will use one of two sets of units:

- `mSmoothScrollbarEnabled == true`: Use units based on the pixel sizes of the visible items in the `RecyclerView`.
- `mSmoothScrollbarEnabled == false`: Use units based on the positions of the visible items in the `RecyclerView`'s adapter.

To control the size of the scrollbar's thumb yourself, you'll have to override these methods... but here's the piece I'm missing: **In all of my experimentation, `computeVerticalScrollExtent()` is never called by the system**. That said, we can still show some progress here.

First, I've created a simple adapter that shows 500 `CardView`s with the item's position inside. I've enabled fast scrolling with some really simple (but ugly) drawables. Here's what the scrollbar looks like with just a default `LinearLayoutManager` implementation:

[image]

As you've found, with 500 (small) items, the scrollbar thumb is really small and quite hard to tap on. We can make the scrollbar dramatically larger by overriding `computeVerticalScrollRange()` to just return a fixed constant... I picked `5000` essentially at random just to show the major change:

[image]

Of course, now the scrollbar doesn't work like you'd expect; scrolling the list by dragging on it as normal moves the thumb much more than it should, and fast scrolling the list by dragging on the thumb moves the list much less than it should.

On my device, with the randomly-chosen range of `5000`, overriding `computeVerticalScrollOffset()` as follows makes the scrollbar thumb move perfectly as I scroll the list by dragging on it:

```
@Override
public int computeVerticalScrollRange(RecyclerView.State state) {
    return 5000;
}

@Override
public int computeVerticalScrollOffset(RecyclerView.State state) {
    return (int) (super.computeVerticalScrollOffset(state) / 23.5f);
}
```

However, this still doesn't fix the second issue: dragging on the thumb itself doesn't correctly scroll the list. As I mentioned above, it would seem like the appropriate thing to do here would be to override `computeVerticalScrollExtent()`, but the system never invokes this method. I've even overridden it to simply throw an exception, and my app never crashes.

Hopefully this at least helps point people in the right direction for a full solution.

PS: The implementations of `computeVerticalScrollRange()` and `computeVerticalScrollOffset()` I've included in this answer are intentionally simple (read: bogus). "Real" implementations would be much more complex; the default `LinearLayoutManager` implementations take into account device orientation, the first and last visible items in the list, the number of items off-screen in both directions, smooth scrolling, various layout flags, and so on.

Comment: `computeVerticalScrollExtent()` is called if scrollbars are set e.g. `android:scrollbars="vertical"`. That's not helping fast scroll though.

Comment: Did you solve this? Can you please share full source code of the solution? Maybe on Github?

Comment: Not Helping Kindly post the full class or git link .

Answer (score 6):

I solved this problem by copying the FastScroller class from 
android.support.v7.widget.FastScroller

Then I removed the fast scroll enabled from the xml and applied fastscroller using the below code:

```
StateListDrawable verticalThumbDrawable = (StateListDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.fastscroll_sunnah);
Drawable verticalTrackDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.fastscroll_line_drawable);
StateListDrawable horizontalThumbDrawable = (StateListDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.fastscroll_sunnah);
Drawable horizontalTrackDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.fastscroll_line_drawable);

Resources resources = getContext().getResources();
new FastScroller(recyclerView, verticalThumbDrawable, verticalTrackDrawable,
                horizontalThumbDrawable, horizontalTrackDrawable,
                resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.fastscroll_default_thickness),
                resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.fastscroll_minimum_range),
                resources.getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.fastscroll_margin));
```

Inside the FastScroller Class I extended the defaultWidth:

```
FastScroller(RecyclerView recyclerView, StateListDrawable verticalThumbDrawable,
        Drawable verticalTrackDrawable, StateListDrawable horizontalThumbDrawable,
        Drawable horizontalTrackDrawable, int defaultWidth, int scrollbarMinimumRange,
        int margin) {
    ...
    this.defaultWidth = defaultWidth;
    ...
```

Then I updated the code in this method:

```
void updateScrollPosition(int offsetX, int offsetY) {
...
mVerticalThumbHeight = Math.max(defaultWidth * 4, Math.min(verticalVisibleLength,
                (verticalVisibleLength * verticalVisibleLength) / verticalContentLength));
...
...
mHorizontalThumbWidth = Math.max(defaultWidth * 4, Math.min(horizontalVisibleLength,
                (horizontalVisibleLength * horizontalVisibleLength) / horizontalContentLength));
...    
}
```

This ensures that the minimum thumb height/width is 4 times the default width.

Comment: If your list is long, this is also an opportunity to replace the call to `scrollBy` in `verticalScrollTo` with a call to `scrollToPosition` (adjusting the calculation accordingly). `scrollBy` results in adapter calls for each and every item across the scroll range which becomes very slow with many items (as least in `recyclerview:1.1.0`).

Comment: Testing this, I've noticed that while it makes the thumb larger, it also lets it be truncated when at the top/bottom. Can you please share full source code of the solution? Maybe on Github?

Comment: It does make the thumb bigger. I will see if I have the gist somewhere

Answer (score 4):

This is a known issue, opened in August 2017: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64729576

Still waiting for recommendations on how to manage `RecyclerView` with fast scroll on large amounts of data. No reply from Google on that issue so far on recommendations :(

The answer from Nabil is similar to a workaround mentioned in the issue. Nabil's answer copies the `FastScroller` class and modifies it to ensure a minimum thumb size, and the workaround in the issue extends `FastScroller` (but it has to stay in the `android.support.v7.widget` package) to ensure the minimum thumb size.

Comment: I found in this issue link to fast scroller library, which solved my problem: https://github.com/zhanghai/AndroidFastScroll

Comment: @Anrimian This is only from API 21, and RecyclerView supports from before...

Comment: @Anrimian Thanks a bunch, exactly what i was looking for

Comment: @Anrimian this one helped. thanks

Answer (score 1):

[Nabil Mosharraf Hossain's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47846873/recyclerview-fast-scroll-thumb-height-too-small-for-large-data-set/49233865#49233865) solved this issue. I just wanted to post some details for future reference.

By default, instead of calling `computeVerticalScrollExtent()` in LinearLayoutManager, thumb size and thumb position are calculated in FastScroller class in `updateScrollPosition` method.

This is the formula for thumb size:

```
this.mVerticalThumbHeight =
Math.min(verticalVisibleLength, verticalVisibleLength * verticalVisibleLength / verticalContentLength);
```

`verticalVisibleLength` is a length of the part of the recycler's content that is visible on the screen. `verticalContentLength` is length of the whole content of the recycler. So the thumb takes up from the screen the same proportion as visible content takes up from the whole content. Which means that if recycler content is very long - thumb would be very small.

To prevent this, we can override `mVerticalThumbHeight` as [Nabil Mosharraf Hossain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8007959/nabil-mosharraf-hossain) suggested. I did it this way, so the thumb would still has the same proportional size but not lower that 100 pixels:

```
this.mVerticalThumbHeight = Math.max(100,
Math.min(verticalVisibleLength, verticalVisibleLength * verticalVisibleLength / verticalContentLength));
```

But. Overriding only the thumb size would lead to some inconsistencies in thumb movement near the top and the bottom of the screen because its position would behave the same way like the thumb is still very small. To prevent this we can also override thumb position.

Default formula for thumb position doesn't take the thumb size into consideration and just uses the fact the it is proportional to the screen size. So I found this formula to work. But I can't quite remember what does it do exactly.

```
this.mVerticalThumbCenterY = (int)((verticalVisibleLength - mVerticalThumbHeight) * offsetY
/ ((float)verticalContentLength - verticalVisibleLength) + mVerticalThumbHeight / 2.0);
```

Comment: although `mVerticalThumbHeight` portion works well, `mVerticalThumbCenterY` has some glitches as far my test...where should `mVerticalThumbCenterY` be? before or after `mVerticalThumbHeight` update? either way, its has some bug

Comment: @TouhidulIslam mVerticalThumbCenterY is defined right after mVerticalThumbHeight in the same method. And you right, it still has some glitches. For example when recycler is very long if you scroll to the top or to the bottom, recycler stops not on the first or last element but the one before that. Is this what you talking about or where is something else?

Comment: sometimes the Thumb just vanishes when a single view is too big that it doesn't fit in a single screen, need scrolling. Then I print the `mVerticalThumbCenterY` values to see what is happening. I found, `mVerticalThumbCenterY` becomes negative when the stated scenario occurs

Comment: i solved the issue, it was just plain old integer overflow issue!
instead of `this.mVerticalThumbCenterY = (int)((verticalVisibleLength - mVerticalThumbHeight) * offsetY
/ ((float)verticalContentLength - verticalVisibleLength) + mVerticalThumbHeight / 2.0);` **i had to do** `this.mVerticalThumbCenterY = (int)((verticalVisibleLength - mVerticalThumbHeight) 
/ ((float)verticalContentLength - verticalVisibleLength)* offsetY + mVerticalThumbHeight / 2.0);`

Comment: Did you solve this? Can you please share full source code of the solution? Maybe on Github?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to adjust the size of the scrollbar thumb, however I'm not completely there yet. Just like [the answer of Ben P.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48157813/11247754) I've used the default properties `app:fastScrollEnabled` and all the track & thumb drawable properties and created a custom `LinearLayoutManager`.

```
    class FastScrollLayoutManager(context: Context) : LinearLayoutManager(context) {

        override fun scrollVerticallyBy(dy: Int, recycler: RecyclerView.Recycler?, state: RecyclerView.State?): Int {
            return super.scrollVerticallyBy(dy * 2, recycler, state)
        }

        override fun computeVerticalScrollRange(state: RecyclerView.State): Int {
            return super.computeVerticalScrollRange(state) / 2
        }

        override fun computeVerticalScrollOffset(state: RecyclerView.State): Int {
            return super.computeVerticalScrollOffset(state) / 2
        }
    }
```

By dividing the result of `computeVerticalScrollRange()` and `computeVerticalScrollOfsett()` with 2, the scroll thumb will become 2x bigger. If you then multiply the scrolling speed with 2, the scroll speed will be on the right scale again. Dragging the thumb of the scrollbar will be working perfectly and the size of the thumb will be 2x bigger than before.

However, this is not yet a final solution. By increasing the scroll speed, the 'normal' scrolling (not using the scrollbar) won't be smooth anymore.

Comment: Did you solve this? Can you please share full source code of the solution? Maybe on Github?

Comment: @androiddeveloper I ended up using this library: https://github.com/zhanghai/AndroidFastScroll

Comment: It does seem very good, but the minSdkVersion is 21, while RecyclerView supports less... Do you know of a way to use it only from API 21, while using the one that RecyclerView offers on below?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to copy `FastScroller` class, you can intercept `ACTION_DOWN` touches yourself, determine the desired touch area and change the final Y coordinate:

```
class FastScrollerTouchesFixRecyclerView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : RecyclerView(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    private val thumbSize = 48 * context.resources.displayMetrics.density

    override fun onInterceptTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        // If necessary, add the RTL check yourself
        if (event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN && event.x > width - thumbSize) {
            val middleScreenPos = computeVerticalScrollOffset() + height / 2
            val thumbCenter = height * middleScreenPos / computeVerticalScrollRange()

            if (abs(event.y - thumbCenter) < thumbSize / 2) {
                event.setLocation(event.x, thumbCenter.toFloat())
            }
        }
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event)
    }
}
```